# Significance of the length of the Perron eigenvector

Tags: matrices, sp.spectral-theory, eigenvalues

Let $A$ be a positive square matrix. Perron-Frobenius theory says that there exist $\lambda,v$ with $Av=\lambda v$ and $\lambda$ equals the spectral radius of $A$, $\lambda$ is simple, and $v$ is positive.

Now consider also the *left* Perron eigenvector $u^T A=\lambda u^T$. Another result of Perron-Frobenius theory is that

$$\lim_{m\to \infty} \frac{A^m}{\lambda^m} = \frac{v u^T}{u^T v}.$$

Suppose $\|v\|=1$. The above result says that the "correct" normalization for u is $u^T v=1$ rather than the more usual $u^T u=\|u\|^2=1$. This motivates the question: **what is the significance of the ratio**

$$\frac{u^T v}{u^T u} ?$$

Are there matrices $A$ for which this ratio is arbitrarily large? Arbitrarily small? Does this ratio determine any properties of $A$? Note that if $A$ is symmetric, then $u=v$ and this ratio is always equal to $1$, but that's not the case in general for arbitrary $A$. Could it be the case that this ratio is measuring how far $A$ is from being symmetric?

Note too that this normalization is necessary so that the limit $\frac{v u^T}{u^T v}$ is a projection matrix (i.e. that its only non-zero eigenvalue is one). In this context, I understand why the normalization is necessary, but I'm interested in *the amount of normalization necessary with respect to the length of $u$*.

Any pointers appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT** In the comments, it is argued that the real quantity of interest in this setup is

$$\frac{\left( u^T v \right)^2}{\left(u^T u \right) \left( v^T v \right)}.$$

This quantity is also of interest to me, and an acceptable replacement for my original question.

Comment: No significance. It's just a question of scaling. $u^Tv=1$ ensures that $u$ and $v$ are dual eigenvectors. With this scaling, there is still one degree of freedom: you can multiply $u$ by a constant $t$ and divide $v$ by the same constant (notice that this rescaling scales your ratio by a factor of $1/t^2$).

Comment: Perhaps the true quantity to understand is $(u^T v)^2/((u^T u)(v^T v))$ then?

Comment: @AnthonyQuas the ratio is still uniquely defined as stated (with $v$ having unit length). In any case, Kevin Casto proposes an alternative.

Comment: @KevinCasto, yes, studying that alternative would also be of interest!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That quantity $s = \frac{|u^Tv|}{\|u\|\|v\|}$ is the inverse of the eigenvalue condition number. The smaller it is, the more sensitive to perturbation the Perron value is.

More precisely, any perturbed matrix $A+E$ with $\|E\| \leq \varepsilon$ has a Perron value $\tilde{\lambda}$ that satisfies $|\tilde{\lambda}-\lambda| \leq \frac{\varepsilon}{s} + \mathcal{O}(\varepsilon^2)$. See e.g. Section 7.2.2 of Golub and Van Loan's *Matrix Computations* 4th ed.

In addition, note that if $A$ is normal then $s=1$ (its maximum possible value) and the Perron value is perfectly conditioned; while if $\lambda$ is a defective eigenvalue (e.g. $A = \begin{bmatrix}1  & 1 \\ 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$) then $s=0$. So rather than a "distance from symmetric" I'd say that $1-s$ is a "distance from normal" or $s$ is a "distance from defective".

Comment: This answers my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For example, if $$ \eqalign{A &= \pmatrix{1 & t\cr 1 & 1\cr},\ 
v = \pmatrix{\sqrt{t}\cr 1},\ u =\pmatrix{1\cr \sqrt{t}},\cr
\frac{(u^T v)^2}{(u^T u)(v^T v)} &= \frac{4t}{(1+t)^2} \to 0 \ \text{as}\ t \to \infty} $$
By Cauchy-Schwarz we always have
$$ 0 < \frac{(u^T v)^2}{(u^T u)(v^T v)} \le 1$$ 
with equality on the right iff $u$ is a scalar multiple of $v$.

Note also that if $A$ is doubly stochastic, $u = v = (1,\ldots,1)^T$.  Not all doubly stochastic matrices are symmetric.

Comment: Interestingly, the ratio equals $1$ exactly when the matrix is symmetric.

Comment: well $u=v$ if matrix is symmetric, so it is not a surprise ?

Comment: I didn't say it was a surprise, I said it was interesting in light of my conjecture (see original post) that this ratio measures how far $A$ is from being symmetric.

Comment: @RobertIsrael - I just saw your latest edit - perhaps this ratio being equal to $1$ is an indication of normality rather than symmetricity.

Comment: Doubly stochastic matrices need not be normal either.

Comment: Woops I was thinking of permutation matrices.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how helpful, but you can say the following: in general, $u$ (or the 1-dimensional eigenspace spanned by it) is the orthogonal complement to the span of all the (right-) eigenvectors *except* $v$, call this $W$. The quantity I mentioned is $\cos^2$ of the angle between $v$ and $u$, which is $1 - \cos^2$ of the angle between $v$ and $W$.

So if you know things about just the right eigenvectors, you can say things about this quantity. For example, it's close to 0 if $v$ is close to $W$, and close to 1 if $v$ is close to being perpendicular to $W$.

Comment: This is very helpful! I take it the other way around though: knowing only $v$ and $u$ can say something about $v$ and $W$. Now I'm wondering whether $v$ being close to $W$ affects the convergence rate of power methods for computing eigenvalues...